# Get clipboard binary data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipboard

Basically im trying to get the whole clipboard in bytes, so I could save it to a file.

If I use `win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()` it only works with text,

and I need a way to get picture, files and even compounds.

I don't need anything fancy to read out the values, I just need all the binary data!

Comment: @greg-449 Sry, missclick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps? with this you get the picture bytes. https://www.devdungeon.com/content/grab-image-clipboard-python-pillow

Comment: Sadly this will only work with pictures, otherwise it will return `NoneType`

Comment: The best I could find is this https://python-forum.io/Thread-How-can-I-paste-an-entire-file-from-clipboard-to-a-folder

Comment: Please summarize the linked page in your answer here so your answer doesn't become useless in case of link-rot.
[Why is linking bad?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/174780)
| 
[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/174780)